# Странное поведение "hdiutil"

Tags: bash, macos

```
clear; read -p "Желаемый размер раздела в GB? = " s; ((s= 10**9*s/512)); read -p "Введите название раздела? = " n; cn=`scutil --get ComputerName`; mac_addr=`ifconfig en0 | grep "ether"`; mac_addr=${mac_addr#*ether}; mac_addr=${mac_addr// /}; mac_addr=${mac_addr//:/}; read -p "Точка Монтирования = " mp; sudo hdiutil create -size ${s}b -fs JHFS+X -volname "${n}" -type SPARSEBUNDLE "/Volumes/${mp}/${cn}_${mac_addr}.sparsebundle" && echo "Done"

Желаемый размер раздела в GB? = 10
Введите название раздела? = rrr
Точка Монтирования = Data
Password:
hdiutil: create failed - Operation not permitted
```

Не работает, при этом файл /Volumes/Data/Air_60c22700b922.sparsebundle создаётся, но "нет подключённых файловаых систем"

```
clear; read -p "Желаемый размер раздела в GB? = " s; ((s= 10**9*s/512)); read -p "Введите название раздела? = " n; cn=`scutil --get ComputerName`; mac_addr=`ifconfig en0 | grep "ether"`; mac_addr=${mac_addr#*ether}; mac_addr=${mac_addr// /}; mac_addr=${mac_addr//:/}; read -p "Точка Монтирования = " mp; sudo hdiutil create -size ${s}b -fs JHFS+X -volname "${n}" -type SPARSEBUNDLE "/Volumes/${cn}_${mac_addr}.sparsebundle" && sudo mv "/Volumes/${cn}_${mac_addr}.sparsebundle" "/Volumes/${mp}" && echo "Done"

Желаемый размер раздела в GB? = 10
Введите название раздела? = rrr
Точка Монтирования = Data
created: /Volumes/Air_60c22700b922.sparsebundle
Done

ls -@ln /Volumes/Data/Air_60c22700b922.sparsebundle
total 16
-rwxrwxrwx  1 501  0  498 18 окт 03:50 Info.bckup
-rwxrwxrwx  1 501  0  498 18 окт 03:50 Info.plist
drwxrwxrwx  1 501  0  432 18 окт 03:50 bands
-rwxrwxrwx  1 501  0    0 18 окт 03:50 token
```

Работает

Что я делаю не так?

Заранее благодарен за помощь!

P.S.

```
uname -a
Darwin Air.local 13.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Mon Jan 11 18:17:34 PST 2016; root:xnu-2422.115.15~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

GNU bash, версия 4.4.0(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0)
```

Data — это название сетевого диска Time Capsule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
clear; read -p "Желаемый размер раздела в GB? = " s; ((s= 10**9*s/512)); read -p "Введите название раздела? = " n; cn=`scutil --get ComputerName`; mac_addr=`ifconfig en0 | grep "ether"`; mac_addr=${mac_addr#*ether}; mac_addr=${mac_addr// /}; mac_addr=${mac_addr//:/}; read -p "Точка Монтирования = " mp; hdiutil create -size ${s}b -fs JHFS+X -volname "${n}" -type SPARSEBUNDLE "/Volumes/${mp}/${cn}_${mac_addr}.sparsebundle" && echo "Done"

Желаемый размер раздела в GB? = 10
Введите название раздела? = rrr
Точка Монтирования = Data
created: /Volumes/Data/Air_60c54700b918.sparsebundle
Done
```

The matter of rights on the network drive:

```
DIDiskImageCreateWithCFURL: creator returned 0
::getBandEntry: chown() - 501
Завершение…
DIHLDiskImageCreate() returned 1
hdiutil: create: returning 1
hdiutil: create failed - Операция не разрешена

по этому файл создаётся, но потом операция завершается с ошибкой, до того как он делает форматирование:
DIDiskImageCreateWithCFURL: creator returned 0
DI_kextWaitQuiet: about to call IOServiceWaitQuiet...
DI_kextWaitQuiet: IOServiceWaitQuiet took 0.000011 seconds
Форматирование…
Завершение…
created: /Volumes/backup/test13.sparsebundle
```